# Transfer Functions and Stability?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, signal-processing

Given a transfer function:
$$f = \frac{\sigma(\sigma+1)}{s - \sigma + 1}$$
where $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to check the stability of the above function.

*Attempt*:

Pole(s) of the function: $s = \sigma -1$

*Question*: Are the zero(s) of the function: $z_1 = 0$ and $z_2 = -1$? $s$ does not appear in the numerator, so this is confusing to me

Continuing, I know the system will be stable if the pole(s) of $f$ have a negative real part, but I need to be careful of pole-zero cancellation.

That is, if $\sigma = 1$, would the pole cancel with $z_1$? and $f$ reduce to:
$$f = \frac{2}{s}$$
which is not stable since there are no zeros and $s = 0$

Similarly, if $\sigma = -1$
$$f = \frac{-1(-1 + 1)}{s-(-1)+1} = \frac{0}{s+2}$$
which is $0$, so how do I handle this case?

The other cases would not have any cancellations, so $f$ should be stable as long as $\sigma < 1$ exlcuding $\sigma = -1$

I am incredibly rusty with transfer functions, so any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the closed or open loop system?

Comment: @copper.hat BIBO stability or 'external', which should be just related to the denominator of $f$ assuming it was factored

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means. The function above has no zeros. I have no idea what could cause a cancellation.

Comment: @copper.hat that's all I needed to know! Thanks!

Comment: The case $0/(s - 2)$ is a bit more interesting as it is BIBO stable, but the state still blows up to infinity.